# python2.7: best way to defer signal handling?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, signals

If my signal handler tries to print or use locks, then the program occasionally gets stuck here:

```
#0  0x000014b2da524827 in futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (private=0, 
    abstime=0x0, expected=0, futex_word=0x13ddac0)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:205
#1  do_futex_wait (sem=sem@entry=0x13ddac0, abstime=0x0)
    at sem_waitcommon.c:111
#2  0x000014b2da5248d4 in __new_sem_wait_slow (sem=0x13ddac0, abstime=0x0)
    at sem_waitcommon.c:181
#3  0x000014b2da52497a in __new_sem_wait (sem=<optimized out>)
    at sem_wait.c:29
#4  0x0000000000558058 in ?? ()
#5  0x00000000004ae0a4 in PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs ()
```

(and I can't get into pdb because signals stop working and I couldn't think of how to get into pdb besides sending the program a signal)

Upon further research, Python signal handlers must [defer their work](https://bugs.python.org/issue24283) if they print or use locks. What is the best way to do this? Would writing to a pipe using `os.write` be safe? Are there any lighter weight options?

According to [this discussion about C](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16755506), a write to a pipe from within a signal handler is safe, and is also the recommended way to defer signal handler work. In other words, no simpler method has been found that is safe and general for C code. Is the same true in Python 2.7?